# Use of Lockhart's *Measurement* in a course?

Tags: undergraduate-education, geometry, undergraduate-research

I greatly admire Paul Lockhart's
*Measurement* 
([Harvard Press](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674284388)).
Many of you know him through
[A Mathematician's Lament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematician%27s_Lament).
One review of *Measurement* said,

> “Here Lockhart offers the positive side of the math education story by showing us how math should be done. *Measurement* offers a permanent solution to math phobia by introducing us to mathematics as an artful way of thinking and living.”

But I do not see a way to integrate this into a conventional
mathematics course (say, for undergraduates).

> ***Q***. Can anyone see a way to use Lockhart's *Measurement*
>   in mathematics education, either in a conventional course,
>   or as a supplement, or for guided independent study?

---

<sup>*Measurement*: Table of Contents:</sup>


          
[image: MeasContents]

---

*Added*. One could imagine Part One supplementing a first course
in Geometry, and Part Two supplementing Calculus I. But the style
is so unique that I can't decide if it would be better 
for these sections to proceed or to follow geometry/calculus. But really the true thrust of the book
is to understand what it means to pursue mathematics.

I like this quote (where "we" = "we mathematicians"):

> We're always working at the edge of the unknown,
>   and we're always stuck.

---

A few SE citations of *Measurement*:

- MESE: [What are some great books for exploring mathematics? (...)](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/4199/511).
- MSE: [Explaining what real math is to a high school student](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/284446/237)
  .
- HSM: [When was 4D space “conceived of”?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/9567/606).

Comment: This sounds interesting.  Enough so that perhaps you can give a few examples after your citations of some specific topics 'covered' (I assume, from the *Lament*, that there isn't coverage in the usual sense)?  For those of us who haven't read *Measurement*, this question could easily become an insider knowledge game if the answers also assume one has read it.  Not that you intended that, of course!  Just trying to be proactive - hope people have ideas!

Comment: @kcrisman: Good point. I've pasted in the table of contents, but you are right: there is not coverage in the usual sense.

Comment: This is a wildly insufficient response, but since relatively little has been posted thus far: I lent a copy of this book to a student who was looking for extra math reading. She returned it after reading a bit and finding it not to be engaging. (FWIW: I have taught a lesson using the *Lament* before; see part two [**here**](https://maths4maryams.org/mathed/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/WikiLetter-8.pdf) (pdf).) Anyway: If *Measurement* is to be used in a course, then my $n=1$ experience is that more structure than offering it as an independent reading will be necessary. Sorry I don't have more!

Comment: (1) Frankly, the very first sentence of the Lament says enough for me to completely discard it: "A musician wakes from a terrible nightmare. In his dream he finds himself in a society where music education has been made mandatory." One can see where he leads from a mile away. No, I do not agree with the analogy. The importance of being able to compare amounts, to do basic arithmetic, to calculate percents, to figure out whether one can make it on the remaining gas without filling up, all these small things happen every day.

Comment: (2) Music is optional, on another hand it can be done without much theory (yes, I am fully aware of musical theory, but it is not needed for basic singing or even decent playing and arranging). He is lamenting that future bright minds are indoctrinated and spoiled. The problem is, most school students are not the bright minds he is imagining, they just want to get out this de-facto juvenile prison, where they are stuck for six hours a day for thirteen years of their life. When I learned about "Measurement" I put it my Amazon list. Six years since, it still sits in the list.

Comment: I just ran across an [MAA review of *Measurement*](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/measurement). She says, "It could easily be classified as a textbook for use in a 12th-grade mathematics elective, a mathematics service course, college geometry, or in a capstone course for mathematics majors."

Comment: PS. Lockhart has a new book out, [Arithmetic](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/arithmetic-0).

Comment: (1) I wonder why you quoted the opinion part, but omitted the more factual part, "the foci of the book are classic and analytic geometry". (2) "The author then discusses the nature of problem-solving: “What is a problem?”, “How do we teach problem-solving?” " — Polya's name is conspicuously absent from the review. (3) Reading the table of contents http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674284388&content=toc I got a feeling that the book is better suited for enrichment of a middle schooler, than as a high school textbook.

Comment: @RustyCore: I myself do not entirely agree with the MAA review. I certainly don't think it could serve as a textbook. I just thought I would include a reviewer's opinion on the question I posed. I've read both Polya and Lockhart. Both are valuable, but quite different.